# Response Caching using VaryByQueryKeys with dictionary querystring argument

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, responsecache, varybyquerykeys

My ASP.NET Core MVC application has a controller method with a dictionary argument, passed via the request query string:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> filterCriteria)
{
}
```

The application uses Response Caching with the `VaryByQueryKeys` option to return cached responses for requests that have previously been served. This works as required for simple querystring values, using an attribute on the method with the following syntax: `[ResponseCache(VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "argName" }, Duration = 20)]`

However, I want to use it with a dictionary argument illustrated above.

Can it be used with an object argument like a dictionary? What is the syntax to use when specifying the list of querystring keys in the `ResponseCache` attribute?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can specify queryKeys for a dictionary argument using the following syntax:

```
[ResponseCache(VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "argName[key1]", "argName[key2]", ... }, Duration = 20)]
```

Comment: or just with * ```VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" }```